# Why does installing Postgres on MacBook Pro M1 fails?

Tags: postgresql, macos

I get this error while installing Postgres on my M1 MacBook Pro `Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly The database cluster initialisation failed.`

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure anyone can tell from that. Do you not have any sort of log file from whatever installer you are using?

Comment: Try this one, never let me down: https://postgresapp.com